# Change element reference without using eval

Tags: javascript, protractor

What I am trying to do is have one function I can use to perform the same job of grabbing text from an element, except I want to change the locator where I want to pull the text from

```
const firstNameError = by.id('firstNameError');
const lastNameError = by.id('lastNameError');
const dateError = by.id('dateError');
const emailError = by.id('emailAddressError');


this.checkWarning = function(locator) {
    return browser.findElement(eval(locator + 'Error')).getText();
};
```

So above, currently works but uses an eval function(which I would rather avoid). So I call .checkWarning and pass in 'firstName' for example and it will use the firstNameError const.

I have tried implementing things like below where I have a list of locators and then I have ammended the function to access the list based on the locator e.g

```
const locatorValues =
{
    'firstName': 'firstNameError',
    'lastName': 'lastNameError',
    'date': 'dateError',
    'email': 'emailError',
};

this.checkWarning = function(locator) {
    return browser.findElement(locatorValues[locator]).getText();
};
```

But again to get that to work I would have to wrap an eval around it. What we be the best approach to referencing my constants based on the locator I would pass into .checkWarning?

Thanks

Comment: You can try to find `window[localtor + 'Error']` (or use `global` instead of `window` if you are not on a browser)

Comment: Look like `const` are not on `window`. I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)** DOM API method solves this issue if your `browser.findElement` function looked like this:

```
findElement = function(loc){
  return document.querySelector("#" + loc);
};
```